# I cannot reach a constant of a class in the same package

Tags: java, eclipse, package, constants

I am building a DJ MAX style game.

I make multiple packages to manage the project. Whenever I reach an important milestone(eg. completed coding main lobby GUI), I copy and paste the previous package and give it a new name. The newly pasted package becomes the new workspace for new features and the original package is kept untouched since then.

Currently, I have 12 packages for the game, which means I am working in package 12.

However, a weird thing happens with constants (static value). I created a constant called REACH_TIME in Main class, but I can use the constant only in partial classes in the package.

For example, let's say there are three classes in package 12: Main, Game, Note. As I said, Main class has a constant called REACH_TIME. I can use that constant in Game class by using the code,

```
    Main.REACH_TIME
```

However, I cannot use the same constant in Note class.

When I move the mouse cursor on the error, the eclipse provides me an option whether I want to define the constant in the main class or not. So I clicked the option to check what is going on, and it defines the constant in the Main class in package 6 which doesn't even have a Game or Note class.

How come a class in package 12 that doesn't even exist in package 6 is connected to the Main class in package 6?

FYI, I connected my project to GitHub through Eclipse. I just checked the local repository and Package 12 and 6 is not mixed.

Comment: Is there another class called `Main` in package 6?

Comment: Basically, the higher numbered package is the copied version of the lower numbered packages, therefore each package has a class called Main.

Comment: that sounds like bad design... why do you have so many copied versions of code? Anyway, you might have imported the Main from package 6. Check your imports